# Remove ssh from repo that no longer exists

Tags: node.js, github, npm, ssh

I'm having a very frustrating error. To preface this: I haven't written hardly any code in about 2 years since an internship ended and I decided to take a break, since then I've reinstalled my Windows 10 and generally haven't touched any of my old code/repos etc.

I was trying to start a new project earlier today and its been about 5h and im about to pull my hair out because I cannot figure out how to (I assume) remove an outdated/non-existent SSH key from a repo that, iirc was run by the internship organization. I have no access to anything under that org and I have absolutely no idea how to resolve this issue. I've searched for hours, reset my keys, re-installed node/npm/git multiple times, deleted node packages, re-made and applied new ssh keys to my github account and nothing works. I'm not completely sure why I'm stuck here as I'm not even working in the same windows folder for this project, it's completely separate but no matter what I try to do I am stuck because of this SSH error tied to some internship almost 3 years ago. I'm losing my mind. I've searched every term I can fathom to remedy this and nothing has worked, so here I am.

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/OldInternOrgName/repo-browser.git
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Can you describe what steps you're taking to get to this point?  You're in a new folder/project?  Are you on the command line or using an IDE?

Comment: @Joe Sure, so I've tried to do this via VSCode Console, CMD & Git CLI and I cannot get anything to work. I've created a new project in multiple different locations on my drive and I get the same error. I can't seem to find a way to just remove this repo from my account completely as I don't need or want anything to do with it.

Comment: what commands are you running?  What steps do you take to make this happen?

Comment: @joe `npm i [package]`. I'm just trying to make a project and install a node package. I can't install anything in any folder anywhere on my hard drive. I get this error

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out what the issue was!

```
Look for a .npm directory in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% (also check .npmrc).
```

https://github.community/t/cannot-create-project-because-of-old-repo-ssh-key/234893/6